# Profit calculation according to the date of each month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new in oracle , I have some question .I want my output table have to three columns named ref_dep_id , due_date,profit_amount ..please help me .
my code is :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table TBL_DEPOSIT_INTEREST_PAYMENT
--------------------------------------------------------



  CREATE TABLE "IRAN"."TBL_DEPOSIT_INTEREST_PAYMENT" 
   (    "REF_DEP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "DUE_DATE" DATE, 
    "PROFIT_AMOUNT" NUMBER
   );


--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table TBL_DEPOSIT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "IRAN"."TBL_DEPOSIT" 
   (    "DEP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE" NUMBER, 
    "REF_BRANCH" NUMBER, 
    "REF_CUSTOMER" NUMBER, 
    "DUE_DATE" DATE, 
    "BALANCE" NUMBER, 
    "OPENING_DATE" DATE, 
    "RATE" NUMBER, 
    "MODALITY_TYPE" NUMBER, 
    "REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING" NUMBER, 
    "REF_CURRENCY" NUMBER, 
    "REF_RATE" NUMBER, 
    "REGION_ID" NUMBER, 
    "REGION_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB" NUMBER, 
    "STC_2" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "CUS_TYPE" NUMBER
   )  ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table TBL_DEPOSIT
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "IRAN"."TBL_DEPOSIT" MODIFY ("DEP_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309166952002,40,60,6664833,to_date('18-JUN-09','DD-MON-RR'),6014,to_date('18-JUN-08','DD-MON-RR'),13,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309166736000,40,60,3884509,to_date('30-JUN-09','DD-MON-RR'),992180,to_date('30-JUN-08','DD-MON-RR'),13,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309165005000,40,60,63674543,to_date('23-OCT-09','DD-MON-RR'),32785,to_date('23-OCT-08','DD-MON-RR'),13,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309167087001,30,60,6670947,to_date('07-MAY-09','DD-MON-RR'),693239,to_date('07-MAY-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (201058140000,30,60,20915955,to_date('10-JUN-09','DD-MON-RR'),278768,to_date('10-JUN-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200252187009,30,60,54840160,to_date('05-AUG-09','DD-MON-RR'),160528,to_date('05-AUG-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200369929009,30,60,72046709,to_date('26-APR-09','DD-MON-RR'),792238,to_date('26-APR-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200370363003,30,60,12857116,to_date('26-APR-09','DD-MON-RR'),307572,to_date('26-APR-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200536619001,30,60,3335361,to_date('16-SEP-09','DD-MON-RR'),3252240,to_date('16-SEP-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200556682003,30,60,26903666,to_date('05-OCT-09','DD-MON-RR'),57499,to_date('05-OCT-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
```

`profit_amount` calculated with formula `balance *rate /12 *100`
and `profit_amount` insert into table for each month
function for each month is :

```sql
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309166952002,40,60,6664833,to_date('18-JUN-09','DD-MON-RR'),6014,to_date('18-JUN-08','DD-MON-RR'),13,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309166736000,40,60,3884509,to_date('30-JUN-09','DD-MON-RR'),992180,to_date('30-JUN-08','DD-MON-RR'),13,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309165005000,40,60,63674543,to_date('23-OCT-09','DD-MON-RR'),32785,to_date('23-OCT-08','DD-MON-RR'),13,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (309167087001,30,60,6670947,to_date('07-MAY-09','DD-MON-RR'),693239,to_date('07-MAY-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,920115120101,4,39915,10020,'?????',14011,14011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (201058140000,30,60,20915955,to_date('10-JUN-09','DD-MON-RR'),278768,to_date('10-JUN-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200252187009,30,60,54840160,to_date('05-AUG-09','DD-MON-RR'),160528,to_date('05-AUG-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200369929009,30,60,72046709,to_date('26-APR-09','DD-MON-RR'),792238,to_date('26-APR-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200370363003,30,60,12857116,to_date('26-APR-09','DD-MON-RR'),307572,to_date('26-APR-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200536619001,30,60,3335361,to_date('16-SEP-09','DD-MON-RR'),3252240,to_date('16-SEP-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
Insert into TBL_DEPOSIT (DEP_ID,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE,REF_BRANCH,REF_CUSTOMER,DUE_DATE,BALANCE,OPENING_DATE,RATE,MODALITY_TYPE,REF_DEPOSIT_ACCOUNTING,REF_CURRENCY,REF_RATE,REGION_ID,REGION_NAME,REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE_SUB,STC_2,CUS_TYPE) values (200556682003,30,60,26903666,to_date('05-OCT-09','DD-MON-RR'),57499,to_date('05-OCT-08','DD-MON-RR'),10,3,92011532010120115320101,4,39916,10020,'?????',13011,13011,1);
```

I use this function

```
create or replace function fnc_get_next_n_month(IN_DATE IN int,duration in int)



RETURN varchar
 
 as 
 
 out_string varchar(2000);
 BEGIN

SELECT LISTAGG(result,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY result)result into   out_string  FROM (

select  
to_char(
    substr(IN_DATE, 1, 4)+
    case when 
    (substr(IN_DATE, 5, 2) + ( b.n ))/12  = 0  then 0 
    else 
    ceil( (substr(IN_DATE, 5, 2) + ( b.n ))/12  ) -1 end
)


||
    CASE
        WHEN mod(substr(IN_DATE, 5, 2) + ( b.n ),12) = 0 then '12' 
        when mod(substr(IN_DATE, 5, 2) + ( b.n ),12) between 1 and 9 then '0'||to_char(mod(substr(IN_DATE, 5, 2) + ( b.n ),12)) 
        else to_char(mod(substr(IN_DATE, 5, 2) + ( b.n ),12))
        end 
        || substr(IN_DATE, 7, 2) result 
FROM dual,(select rownum n from dual connect by level <= duration order by n desc)b ) /*where rownum = 1*/ ;
return out_string;


end ;
```

I want the output table have to 3 columns :

| profit_amount | due_date | ref_dep_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: Please show your current code to calculate the result and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: **your** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **your** solution; an (English, not code) explanation of how to apply your formula to the sample data; and the expected output for your sample data. (Also, remove the duplicate code from the question).

Comment: @sami Please check [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: @sami How can we help when you have not described what the expected output is for your sample data and have not explained (in English) what calculation you are expecting to perform to transform that sample data to the expected output?

Comment: @MT0 I expect that when a person opens a deposit account in the bank, for example, on 03/03/1400, for the next 12 months, interest per month will be calculated with a formula, and in the column of dates after that date, interest per month will be entered.

Comment: @sami Do not respond in comments. [Edit] your question and include the relevant explanations **AND** the expected output for your sample data in the question so that your question is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO TBL_DEPOSIT_INTEREST_PAYMENT (REF_DEP_ID, DUE_DATE, PROFIT_AMOUNT)
SELECT      DEP_ID    "REF_DEP_ID",
            DUE_DATE  "DUE_DATE",
            Round(BALANCE * RATE / 12 * 100, 2) "PROFIT_AMOUNT"
FROM        TBL_DEPOSIT;
```

Your formula from question looks a bit unclear and I left it as in the question. It woud be better if you put some brackets to direct the calculation. Anyway, you would make it right yourself...
R e s u l t :

```sql
REF_DEP_ID                               DUE_DATE  PROFIT_AMOUNT
---------------------------------------- --------- -------------
309166952002                             18-JUN-09     651516.67 
309166736000                             30-JUN-09     107486167 
309165005000                             23-OCT-09    3551708.33 
309167087001                             07-MAY-09    57769916.7 
201058140000                             10-JUN-09    23230666.7 
200252187009                             05-AUG-09    13377333.3 
200369929009                             26-APR-09    66019833.3 
200370363003                             26-APR-09      25631000 
200536619001                             16-SEP-09     271020000 
200556682003                             05-OCT-09    4791583.33
```

**ADDITION**
After the comments - I'm still not sure what are you trying to do. Here is a sample (Just for first row DEP_ID=309166952002) that generates monthly rows (12 of them) along with your db data and transforms Gregorian dates to Julian values (if Julian means solar - I don't know). Anyway here is the code that could be used to insert values into your result table (TBL_DEPOSIT_INTEREST_PAYMENT):

```sql
SELECT      To_Char(d.DEP_ID)    "REF_DEP_ID",
            d.OPENING_DATE "OPENING_DATE",
            d.DUE_DATE  "DUE_DATE",
            Round(d.BALANCE * d.RATE / 12 * 100, 2) "PROFIT_AMOUNT",
            --
            '<--' "DB_DATA", '-->' "SQL_DATES",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By d.DEP_ID Order By m.MONTHS) = 1 THEN d.OPENING_DATE END "START_DATE",
            ADD_MONTHS(d.OPENING_DATE, m.MONTHS) "NEXT_MONTH",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By d.DEP_ID Order By m.MONTHS) = 12 THEN d.DUE_DATE END "END_DATE",
            --
            '-->' "JULIAN_SQL_DATES",
            To_Number( To_Char( CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By d.DEP_ID Order By m.MONTHS) = 1 THEN d.OPENING_DATE END, 'J') ) "J_START_DATE",
            To_Number( To_Char( ADD_MONTHS(d.OPENING_DATE, m.MONTHS), 'J') ) "J_NEXT_MONTH",
            To_Number( To_Char( CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By d.DEP_ID Order By m.MONTHS) = 12 THEN d.DUE_DATE END, 'J') ) "J_END_DATE"
            
FROM
    TBL_DEPOSIT d
INNER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL "MONTHS" FROM Dual Connect By LEVEl <= 12) m ON(1 = 1)
WHERE 
    DEP_ID = 309166952002
ORDER BY m.MONTHS

REF_DEP_ID                               OPENING_DATE DUE_DATE  PROFIT_AMOUNT DB_DATA SQL_DATES START_DATE NEXT_MONTH END_DATE      JULIAN_SQL_DATES J_START_DATE J_NEXT_MONTH J_END_DATE     
---------------------------------------- ------------ --------- ------------- ------- --------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ---------------- ------------ ------------ ---------------
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->       18-JUN-08  18-JUL-08                -->                   2454636      2454666                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-AUG-08                -->                                2454697                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-SEP-08                -->                                2454728                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-OCT-08                -->                                2454758                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-NOV-08                -->                                2454789                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-DEC-08                -->                                2454819                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-JAN-09                -->                                2454850                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-FEB-09                -->                                2454881                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-MAR-09                -->                                2454909                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-APR-09                -->                                2454940                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-MAY-09                -->                                2454970                 
309166952002                             18-JUN-08    18-JUN-09     651516.67 <--     -->                  18-JUN-09  18-JUN-09     -->                                2455001         2455001
```

Comment: @d r thank you a lot , I want the output of the date column of the first row to include the account opening date, and from then on, the next rows will be increased every month, and the dates will be solar instead of Gregorian.

Comment: @d r please take a look  ,I edit my question . I add this function above

Comment: @d r dear friend please help me . can I use this code ?  ' INSERT INTO TBL_DEPOSIT_INTEREST_PAYMENT (REF_DEP_ID, DUE_DATE, PROFIT_AMOUNT)
SELECT      DEP_ID    "REF_DEP_ID",
            fnc_get_next_n_month(IN_DATE IN int,duration in int)   "DUE_DATE",
            Round(BALANCE * RATE / 12 * 100, 2) "PROFIT_AMOUNT"
FROM        TBL_DEPOSIT;
'

Comment: @sami Consider it as your code now. I will look the rest in a few hours and inform you. Can't do it right now, sorry.

Comment: @sami The code from your comment would work if the function returns correct value of type DATE. Function is not ok at all and I don't realy know what values you intend to pass to the function and what do you expect as a return value. Will try to figure it out, though...